# Lower bound for lowest eigenvalue of sum of two special hermitian matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume you have a composition of hermitian matrices $H_{i}$ of the form,

$H=cos(\alpha)H_{1}+sin(\alpha)H_{2}$

with $\alpha\in[0,\tfrac{\pi}{2}]$ and you know the following things:

a) $H_{2}=V^{\dagger}H_{1}V$ is a unitary transformation of $H_{1}$.

b) The lowest eigenvector $v_{i}$ of $H_{i}$ has eigenvalue $\lambda_{i}$. Furthermore you the have the property that,
$$H_{i}v_{j}=\delta_{ij}\lambda_{j}v_{j}.$$
From this we can conclude,
$$v^{\dagger}_{i}v_{j}=\delta_{ij}.$$ Since both matrices related by a unitary mapping $\lambda_{1}=\lambda_{2}$.

c) The spectrum of $H_{i}$ is symmetric, meaning that the eigenvalues come in pairs $\{\lambda_{k},-\lambda_{k}\}$.

My intuition is somehow that the lowest eigenvalue $\lambda$ for the composed Matrix $H$ is bounded from below in the sense that it has to fullfill the property, that
$$\lambda\geq{\lambda_{1}},$$ where the equal sign only holds for $\alpha\in\{0,\tfrac{\pi}{2}\}$.

Maybe one can weaken the condition a),c) in the sense that the matrices $H_{i}$ are not linked by a unitary transformation and the spectrum is not symmetric.

Actually im not able to prove this statement, also i don't have found an counter example, so i would also be happy about that =).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conjecture is not true. I wrote a simple python script which generates random matrices with the properties you want, and after a few runs it gave me a counter-example. Note that we may presume $H_1$ to be diagonal. $H_1$ is then defined by a random list of real numbers (which come in pairs), with smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ and at least one zero eigenvalue, which I call $\lambda_2$. I then generate $H_2$ by swapping the eigenvectors with eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, and doing a random unitary on the rest of the spectrum. After a few runs, I then got the following result for the lowest eigenvalue as a function of $\alpha$:
[image]

I am adding the Python script, since it's a good idea to check I haven't made a mistake. Moreover, this script might be useful to play around with to possibly find some version of the statement that you might like to be true.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import qr
import pylab as plt

chi = 20  #dimension of matrices, must be at least three

#generate diagonal Hermitian matrix H1 = D with the necessary properties
#(lambda_1 = lowest, lambda_2 = 0, lambda_n > lambda_1 for n > 1)
if chi%2==0:
    D = [np.random.random((1))[0] for i in range(chi/2-1)] + [0]
    D = D + [-d for d in D]
else:
    D = [np.random.random((1))[0] for i in range(chi/2)]
    D = D + [0] + [-d for d in D]
D = np.sort(np.array(D))
D = np.append(np.append(D[:1],D[chi/2:chi/2+1]),np.append(D[1:chi/2],D[chi/2+1:]))
H1 = np.diag(D)

#generate H2 by swapping the eigenvectors for lambda1 and lambda2,
#and do a random unitary on rest of spectrum
Ublock = np.random.random((chi-2,chi-2)) + 1j*np.random.random((chi-2,chi-2))
Ublock,_ = qr(Ublock)
X = np.array([[0,1],[1,0]])
U = np.zeros((chi,chi),dtype=complex)
U[0:2,0:2] = X
U[2:,2:] = Ublock
H2 = np.tensordot(np.tensordot(U,H1,(1,0)),U.conj().T,(1,0))

#check lowest eigenvalue as a function of alpha
alpha_list = np.linspace(0,np.pi/2,100)
lowest = []
for alpha in alpha_list:
    H = np.cos(alpha)*H1 + np.sin(alpha)*H2
    e = np.linalg.eigvals(H)
    e = np.sort(np.real(e))
    lowest.append(e[0])
plt.plot(alpha_list/np.pi,lowest)
plt.ylabel(r'lowest eigenvalue')
plt.xlabel(r'$\alpha/\pi$')
plt.savefig('plot.pdf')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to show that this statement is not true.